# java code to launch jar by passing arguments to it

Tags: java, jar, 32bit-64bit

I want to launch an jar file by passing two arguments to it from java code,what i have tried is:

```
File jarFile = new File("path/to/jar/file");
if ((jarFile).exists()) {
                String[] command = new String[5];
                command[0] = "java.exe";
                command[1] = "-jar";
                command[2] = jarFile + "";
                command[3] = "arg1";
                command[4] = "arg2";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                p.waitFor();
} else {
    System.out.println("File is not available");
}
```

code is perfect for launching jar, 
But i want to launch jar file using 32 bit JVM as my drivers are 32 bit only.,
And my machine contains both 32 bit and 64 bit JVM,in order to launch jar using 32 bit JVM i could have hard coded java.exe location like

```
command[0] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_25\\bin\\java.exe"
```

but 
1)what if the end user have installed java in some other location?

2)what if **path** environment variable contains 64 bit JVM location if i just give **java.exe**?
 I tried this below code but i am unable to pass arguments using this method

```
String command = {"rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler ", jarFile  + "" , arg1, arg2}
Process p = Runtime
                   .getRuntime()
                   .exec(command);
```

So is there any other way to launch jar file by passing arguments to it?

Comment: `rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler` should have only one argument, the name of the file for which you want the protocol handler. What happens if you leave out `arg1` and `arg2` when calling it?

Comment: Java in java, this is *inception*.. Why don't you use the jar as dependency and run directly the main class from your jar when needed?

Comment: @mthmulders :i want arg1 and arg2 to be passed to the second jar file, without which second jar file don't work.my whole functionality is present in second jar

Comment: @RC. I think i did not explain my problem properly, here I have two jar files, jar1 is located locally and another(jar2) is downloaded using Java web start when user clicks on link given in web page, so jar2 will pass 2 parameters to jar1 depending upon the link user presses, but locally i have both 32 and 64 bit JVM,i want jar2 to be launched using 32 bit JVM only!,because all my drivers are 32 bit!. But user might have installed JVM where ever he wants,so i can't hard code the path like i mentioned above, and even if i set **PATH** variable,but it is vulnerable, don't want to rely on it.

Comment: Hello @MAHANTESH ,i have a similar problem, did u know how to run jar as for 32 jvm ??

Comment: @SaraSaeed: yeah, if you are using 32 bit machine then Java installed will also be 32 bit only, so no problem if you run the jar. But problem is when you launch jar in 64 bit machine, there if you explicitly want your jar file to be launched using 32 bit JVM then there will be two steps: `1) Set environment variables such that they point to 32 bit JVm` or `2) From command prompt type java -d32 -jar jarName.jar from folder containing jar file`

Answer (score 1):

Use the argument '-d32', i.e.
 java -d32 -jar jarfile arg1 arg2.

java -help can be handy too.